# Display the split result in a select * table query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the following statement - how can I get the expected result?

```
select t1.StudentName, t1.Email, s.items Module
from Student t1
outer apply dbo.Split(t1.Module, ',') s
```

**Current**

```
 StudentName | Email      | Module
    S1       | s1@uni.com | Math
    S1       | s1@uni.com | English
    S1       | s1@uni.com | Science
```

**Expected**

```
StudentName | Email       | Module
                          | Math
S1          | s1@uni.com  | English
                          | Science
```

Notes: Using SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align the output vertically, you may try with the next example. Note, that with `STRING_SPLIT()` the output rows might be in any order and the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   StudentName varchar(100), 
   Email varchar(100),
   Module varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data 
   (StudentName, Email, Module)
VALUES
   ('S1', 's1@uni.com', 'Math,English,Science'),
   ('S2', 's1@uni.com', 'Math,English,Science,Grammar,Sports'),
   ('S3', 's1@uni.com', 'Math,English,Science,Sports'),
   ('S4', 's1@uni.com', 'Math')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN (s.Cnt / 2 + 1) = s.Rn THEN d.StudentName END AS StudentName, 
  CASE WHEN (s.Cnt / 2 + 1) = s.Rn THEN d.Email END AS Email, 
  s.Module
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT 
      [value] AS Module, 
      COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Cnt,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Rn
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(d.Module, ',') 
) s
```

Result:

```
-----------------------------------
StudentName Email           Module
-----------------------------------
                            Math
S1          s1@uni.com      English
                            Science
                            Math
                            English
S2          s1@uni.com      Science
                            Grammar
                            Sports
                            Math
                            English
S3          s1@uni.com      Science
                            Sports
S4          s1@uni.com      Math
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on expected result you need `case` expression :

```
select (case when s.items = 'English' then t1.StudentName end) as StudentName ,
       (case when s.items = 'English' then t1.Email end) as Email,
       s.items Module
from Student t1 outer apply 
     dbo.Split(t1.Module, ',') s;
```

If you want specific row should populate `StudentName &  Email` regardless of `Module` then you can use `row_number()`.

Comment: is there a method without hardcoding? Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this (may need to change the `idx` column to match your split function):

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/74464/1

```
select 
  case when s.idx = 0 then t1.StudentName else '' end AS StudentName, 
  case when s.idx = 0 then t1.Email else '' end as Email, 
  s.items Module
from Student t1
outer apply dbo.Split(t1.Module, ',') s
order by t1.StudentName, s.idx
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in SQL Server 2017

```
With cte as (select t1.StudentName, t1.Email, s.value, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentName,email ORDER BY StudentName) rn
from Student t1
outer apply STRING_SPLIT(t1.Module, ',') s)
select StudentName,email, value from (select case when c1.rn = c2.rn and c1.rn = 1 then c1.StudentName
                                           else null
                                           end as StudentName,
                                      case when c1.rn = c2.rn and c1.rn = 1 then c1.email 
                                           else null
                                           end as email,
                                      case when c1.value = c2.value then c1.value
                                           else null
                                           end as value
                               from cte c1 join cte c2
                               on c1.StudentName = c2.StudentName
                               and c1.email = c2.email)t
where t.value is not null
```